# Allocating memory of a variable with the size of a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

Here's my code, I have a 2D vector and I need to take the size of its row and column to a new variable known as visited ,but throwing an error

```
int main() {
    vector<vector<char>>a;
    int n= a.size();
    int m = a[0].size();
    bool vertices= new bool [n][m];
    
}
```

Getting this error

> 

```
Line 5: Char 33: error: array size is not a constant expression
>     bool vertices= new bool [n][m];
>                                 ^ Line 5: Char 33: note: read of non-const variable 'm' is not allowed in a constant expression Line 4:
> Char 9: note: declared here
>     int m = a[0].size();
>         ^ 1 error generated.
```

Unable to resolve

Comment: Think about what happens when s == 1. Also read the question carefully - I don't think you fully understand the problem.

Comment: Is the entire definition of the question you are trying to answer necessary?

Comment: What's the point of `i`? It's incremented each time through the loop, but never used for anything.

Comment: Chose a better title for your question please. Your title does not say anything about your question. Write some logs(some simple sprintfs should work too) in your loops and watch cpu usage.

Comment: What's the time limit, and how long does your code take to finish? Aside from the time limit, is your code correct? Does it print the correct answer for any input?

Comment: So you just copy/pasted the homework assignment and expect results?

Answer (score 2):

The original code tries to determine the number of hits required by summing the widths of the three blocks (`w = w1 + w2 + w3;`) and repeatedly dividing that by the strength S until the remaining width `w` becomes zero. If the strength S is 1 (and therefore `w1`, `w2` and `w3` are all 1 and their sum is 3), that will loop forever, causing the time limit for the code to be exceeded.

Also, it is not clear how the problem could be solved by division. Rather, the problem as stated involves *subtraction*, not division.

Since there are only three bricks in the stack (and S is at least the width of the largest brick), there are only three cases to consider:

```
if (s >= w1 + w2 + w3)
    hits = 1;
else if (s >= w1 + w2 || s >= w3 + w2)
    hits = 2;
else
    hits = 3;
```

A general solution to handle an arbitrarily sized pile of bricks is out of scope for the problem, so does not need to be considered.

Comment: Maybe add a little context?  i.e. if this is the answer to a question, what question exactly does it address?  Why does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When `s` == 1, the instruction `w = w/s;` won’t modify `w`. You program will loop forever because the condition to terminate the loop is when `w == 0`.

This explains the time exceeded that you reported.

Note that `w=w/s;` won’t give you the right answer anyway. Have you understood the question ? Read again.

A side remark is that you should check that the entered values respect the constrains, and reject the input if not.